# Discord.py как отправить изображение, файлом во вложении?

Tags: python, файлы, discord.py, asyncio

При отправке изображения через:

`await message.channel.send(file = discord.File())`

Изображение очень сильно сжимается, как отправить изображение во вложение так же как в телеграмм чтобы качество не падало?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось что фотография сжимается только в самом Discord, после скачивания качество нормальное